# Can one kafka producer be used by multiple sinks safely?

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have a project with three different processFunctions. If an error occurs in any of them, then an error object is created and written to the side-output. all three use the same outputTag for the side output.

My question is: do I have to make a new FlinkKafkaProducer for each sideoutput stream or can I just make a new sink for each side output stream with the same FlinkKafkaProducer since all three will write to the same error topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to actually have different sinks, you can actually perform a .union() of the streams and send that to the single sink.

Something like the following should work:

```
stream1 = source.stuff()
stream2 = source.stuff()
stream3 = source.stuff()
stream1.union(stream2, stream3).addSink(kafkaSink)
```